# javascript call to function and wait until jquery fadeout will finish than return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this 2 functions, i want to call to Scnd function an wait until he finish the jquery fadeout

```
async function f() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let mystart = jewishTable.myLoop('play', time);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (mystart == true) {
                console.log(mystart);
                resolve("done!")
            }
        }, 500);
    });
    let result = await promise;
    slider.stopPlay("playNext", "jewishinfo");
} f();
```

2)

```
jewishTable = {
myLoop: function myLoop (action, time) {
    if(action == 'play'){
        $('#jewisTable').fadeIn();

        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#jewisTable').fadeOut()
        }, time);
        return true      
    }
}
```

}

i want to return true ONLY after fadeOut is finish
than call to another function

Comment: well you can not return from an asynchronous method.

Comment: Maybe you can use callbacks from `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

Comment: .fadeOut comes with a way to call a function when it's complete, such as $( "book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {   // Animation complete.
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a promise with `new Promise`. jQuery can return the promise for you, and also has a `delay` method for implementing the delay between the fade-in and fade-out animations:

```js
var time = 1000;
var jewishTable = {
    myLoop: function myLoop (action, time) {
        if(action == 'play'){
            return $('#jewisTable').fadeIn(1000).delay(time).fadeOut(1000).promise();
        }
        return Promise.reject("unsupported action");
    }
}

async function f() {
    await jewishTable.myLoop('play', time);
    console.log("ready for next function...");
    $("#alldone").show();
    //slider.stopPlay("playNext", "jewishinfo");
} f();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="jewisTable" style="display:none">The table fades in and out...</div>
<div id="alldone" style="display:none">All done</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .fadeOut() method takes two parameters. The first is the `duration` which defaults to 400ms, the second is an optional callback to call when the animation is complete.

So try:

```
 $('#jewisTable').fadeOut(400, function() {
   // This is the callback called when `fadeOut()` is complete
 });
```

Comment: But the callback is anonymous function, when he return value, this is return to the parent function, how can i tell to the parrent to return value (to the first function) only after the anonymous is finish?

Comment: The callback doesn't have to be an anonymous function.